# How to set a string length on wysiwyg text? (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, wysiwyg

Is it possible to cut the length of a string in the wysiwyg editor? I have set up some custom post types and on the archive page I want to be able to set a string length limit, if that limit is reached I also want to add ... to the end of it. Some of these posts have multiple paragraphs incase thats an issue.

I have tried many solutions like the following that don't work;

```
<?php echo mb_strimwidth( get_field('event_information'), 0, 10, '…'); ?>
```

Comment: The simplest solution is to use the `excerpt` field. I believe this is limited to 55 words by default but can be changed with a custom filter. Then just add '...' to the end as necessary, making sure to check for any full spots at the end of the text.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this before:

```
<p class="excerpt">
  <?php $customexerpt = get_the_content(); echo wp_trim_words( $customexerpt , '15' ); ?>
</p>
```

But using the excerpt field is probably recomended.